# How to submit input from a dynamically generated form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been tasked with designing an application using Ruby on Rails which allows a business to sign up and then create a question form for users to answer who wish to volunteer doing whatever it may be with that business.
My issue is how can I save each of the users answers to the database once they submit the form. Because I am generating the questions form dynamically (as the amount of questions will vary) each answer has the same label and on form submission only the final answer is saved to the database.
Still fairly new to ruby and I've been looking all over but can't find a solution.

Here is my show.html.erb file that displays the form to the user.

```
<%=form_with(model: [ @user, @user.user_questions.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
<% @organisation.questions.each.with_index do |questions, i| %>
    <h3>Question <%= i+1 %></h3>
    <p> 
        <%= questions.question %>
    </p>
        <p>
            <%= form.text_area :answer %>
        </p>
        <p style=visibility: hidden>
            <%= form.text_field :organisation_id, value: @organisation.id %>
        </p>
        <p style=visibility: hidden>
            <%= form.text_field :create_account_id, value: @user.id %>
        </p>
        <p style=visibility: hidden>
            <%= form.text_field :question_id, value: questions.id %>
        </p>
        <p style=visibility: hidden>
            <%= form.text_field :name, value: @user.username %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
    <p>
        <%= form.submit "Submit Answers"%>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller for handling the form

```
    def show
        @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id])
        @user = CreateAccount.find(params[:create_account_id])
    end

    def create
        @user = CreateAccount.find(params[:create_account_id])
        @answers = @user.user_questions.create(answer_params)

        if @answers.save
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'show'
        end
    end

    private
        def answer_params
            params.require(:user_question).permit(
                        :answer, 
                        :name,
                        :organisation_id, 
                        :create_account_id, 
                        :question_id)
        end
end
```

The actual result of form submission is always the very last input being saved to the database.

Comment: i suggest you should use nested form , here issue in **form.text_area :answer** this line because it does not have any index bind with it , it will only submit the last value it found in the form, you should bind index with it and use nested form for achieve your functionality , good luck